# Convert time string to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I get a DateTime based on a string

e.g:
if I have `mytime = "14:00"`

How can I get a `DateTime` object with current date as the date, unless current time already 14:00:01, then the date should be the next day.

Comment: If you are a targeting a particular timezone, you are better off targeting the timezone. Rather than a specific time. Depending on the you application and if it spans timezones a library will protect you from changes in timezones and will make dealing with time and dates sooo much easier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is as simple as parsing a `DateTime` with an exact format.

Achievable with

```
var dateStr = "14:00";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "H:mm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

The [`DateTime.ParseExact()` (msdn link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method simply allows you to pass the format string you wish as your parse string to return the `DateTime` struct.  Now the `Date` porition of this string will be defaulted to todays date when no date part is provided.

To answer the second part

> How can I get a DateTime object with current date as the date, unless
>   current time already 14:00:01, then the date should be the next day.

This is also simple, as we know that the DateTime.ParseExact will return todays date (as we havevnt supplied a date part) we can compare our Parsed date to `DateTime.Now`. If `DateTime.Now` is greater than our parsed date we add `1` day to our parsed date.

```
var dateStr = "14:00";

var now = DateTime.Now;
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "H:mm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

if (now > dateTime)
    dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx): which will convert the specified string representation of a date and time to its `DateTime` equivalent and returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

```
string inTime="14:00";
if(DateTime.TryParse(inTime,out DateTime dTime))
{
   Console.WriteLine($"DateTime : {dTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS")}");
}
```

Working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IFerKX)

Answer (score 2):

There is a datetime constructor for

```
public DateTime(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int minute,
    int second
)
```

So then parse the string to find the hours, minutes, and seconds and feed that into this constructor with the other parameters supplied by Datetime.Now.Day and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
string myTime = "14:00";            
var v = myTime.Split(":".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
DateTime obj = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, int.Parse(v[0]), int.Parse(v[1]), DateTime.Now.Second);
```